# Aligning frames with common elements

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, image-segmentation

I am new to image processing and had the following question:

I have take some 512-px grayscale images. The images were take in such a way that all images were of the same spot, but there was some variation in each image. For example, the sharpness in each image is not the same, in some images, I see extra information which I would like to neglect if they are not present in the other frames. I was trying to understand if

- there is a better way of aligning frames
- removing artifacts which are not common in all the frames
- improve the sharpness (is there a best know method to do this?)
- do noise reduction (when I try and sharpen an image, my shot noise shoots up)
- do some sort of balanced contrast brightness tweaking such that the signal from the brighter regions do not mess up the signal from the darker regions. Gamma Correction is just a wee bit primitive to help with that. Creates lots of artifacts.

I know this is a very long question, but I am just some help to kick start my work. In return for any help, I can post results of what I observe